# Switching between workbooks stops Worksheet.Change code from running

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a worksheet which when a user selects a drop down a code is fired to hide or unhide specific rows on the sheet. Once it is all filled out, they click submit and the contents of the selections then gets put into a separate file which automatically saves and closes.

All works fine until the submission is done and the sheet is then reactivated the change macro doesn't work anymore until I close and reopen the workbook.

I have a feeling its because its swapped to another workbook in the submitting code and then the change event no longer fires but I could be wrong.

Here is the change code I have put in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = True


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D10")) Is Nothing Then
        'On Error Resume Next
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Select Case Range("D10")
            Case "SELECT...": HideAllROws
            Case "LEARNING": Hide
            Case "LISTENING": Hide
        End Select
        
        Call CLEARBOTTOMOPTIONS
    End If


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D19")) Is Nothing Then
        'On Error Resume Next
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Select Case Range("D19")
            Case "SELECT…": Hide
            Case "Payments": PaymentROws
            Case "VT": VtsRows
            Case "Procedure": ProceedureRows
            Case "Complaint": ComplaintRows
            Case "Incorrect Info Given": IncorrectInfoRows
            Case "FAIL": PaymentROws
            Case "PASS": PassRows
        End Select
    End If
    

             Application.ScreenUpdating = True
             
    End Sub
```

Not sure what Ive missed but google doesnt give the specific answer on this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What does "doesn't work anymore" mean? Does nothing? Does something unexpected? Is not triggered at all ? Raises a runtime error? Do you have any other places in your code where you disable events (and forget to enable them again?)

Comment: It doesnt fire when the workbook is reactivated. So it works fine until one of my macro switches between two workbooks after that it doesnt fire when cells D10 & D19 are changed. Enabled events is only on this macro and not disabled on anything else.

Comment: If `Worksheet_Change` is not triggered at all (check with the debugger!), then it is most likely that somewhere a statement `Application.EnableEvents = False` was issued.

Comment: You where correct! I had missed one enable events which i had forgotten about. Thanks so much.

Comment: Also, be careful with your Ranges. Consider qualifying the ranges from `Range("D10")` to `Me.Range("D10")` for instance.

Comment: What does "Me.Range" achieve and why is this better? Never used that before so would be great to know, thank you

Comment: `Me`, when used in a Worksheet event, such as `Worksheet_Change`, provides a reference to the Worksheet the event is taking place in.

Comment: More generally, in a worksheet's code module, `Me` refers to the worksheet the code module belongs to.  More generally than that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword

Comment: @CLR
I do not think, that when using the Worksheet Class the me is necessary.
Given a Worksheet named a and in the worksheet Class:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D19")) Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print Range("d19").Parent.Name
 End If
End Sub

Now select an other sheet and : 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("a").range("d19").value = 3

Comment: `Me` is not necessary, but still a good practice I think.  A bit like `Range("A1")` vs. the more-explicit `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` in a regular code module...